# fedora 12 sleeping forever error

Tags: fedora, boot

After manually restarting freeze machine due to no response. It stuck on blue screen and gives error as **sleeping forever**. Default partitioned with LVM.

Whether I need to install fresh OS or I can get installed OS back?

Comment: You should consider updating your system as Fedora 12 is not supported [since 2010](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/announce/2010-December/002895.html)

Comment: I will update system after it works.

So what is solution to get work current system?

Comment: Read the documentation but the official way is as far as i know to do a new installation.

Comment: The "sleeping forever" error means your kernel can't find the disks to continue booting.  There are a lot of reasons why this might happen, but as others have mentioned, Fedora 12 isn't even supported anymore.  You might be better off getting a LiveCD of the latest Fedora, and boot from it, and grab whatever data you want to back up and install an updated Fedora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Booted up the system from Ubuntu live media. Install the LVM package which read the LVM partition on disk.

**Run the fsck command on / patition of HDD by root user.**

This will take time to complete and fixes the missing entries. Also this superblock error in fedora.